# The copy/paste/undo hot-keys don't work. Android Studio IDE

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, ide, android-studio-3.1

For some reason I cannot use the following:

- Ctrl + c (copy)
- Ctrl + v (paste)
- Ctrl + z (undo)

In the settings I did the following:
( File > Settings > Keymap )

- Reset Keymap.
- I chose a different type of keymaps (Windows, Gnome, NetBeans, and more).
- I searched for the hot-keys to check that they are correct. Everything was registered correctly.

*I always restarted the IDE*

OS: Zorin OS

- Android Studio Version: Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 4
- Update now: ***Bumbiebee 2021.1.1***

What must have gone wrong ?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

[This worked for me. Everything works fine.](https://askubuntu.com/a/877362/1547375)

At the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:attente/java-non-latin-shortcuts
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**After Invalidate cashes, the problem returns.**